WebView on iOS showing a blank screen on Maui Debugging
While debugging, my iOS webview is blank. When I deploy the app, the webview renders correctly, and when debugging in windows it works no problem. Below is my login page and code behind. I eventually need to snag some cookies on redirect from the page, but first i need the page to render I so not really develop for iOS so Im unsure what else I can provide to help:
XAML:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="FreshMaui.Pages.LoginPage"
         Title="LoginPage">
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*" RowDefinitions="*" WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="1500">
    <WebView x:Name="WebView"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="0"
     MinimumHeightRequest="1000"
     MinimumWidthRequest="200" 
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Navigated="WebView_Navigated"/>
</Grid>

This is the Xaml.cs:
    public LoginPage()
{
    Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, false);
    InitializeComponent();
    WebView.IsVisible = true;
    WebView.Source = "https://[website].com/login.aspx?WL_Type=I&WL_AppId=[appid]&WL_ReturnMethod=FV&WL_Expire=1&ReturnMethod=Get&WL_ReturnUrl=[appurl]://FreshMaui/Pages/LoginPage.xaml?p1=v1";
    }

Another snippet I can provide: When I travel to the url in Safari is DOES mention that it is an untrusted ssl certificate and I have the following in my info.plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>[App Name]</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>[AppId]</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>24000</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/icon44_ios_g.appiconset</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
    </array>
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  
</dict>
</plist>



Do you run the app on an iOS simulator or your physical device? May I ask the detailed VS version you are using and the detailed environment information like Xcode version and so on?

Also, if your app requires a connection to an insecure website, you should always enter the domain as an exception using the NSExceptionDomains key instead of turning ATS off completely using the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key.

im using VS2022 17.10.0 preview 2.0,
I also attempted the NSExceptionDomain keys as well, im still recieving a blank screen on my webview.

What if you remove the Navigated="WebView_Navigated", would that still become blank?

No, the navigated event was something I added to try and troubleshoot what was going on, it was still blank before i added it


Have you enabled XAML Hot Reload? 2. Consider reporting this on Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues as this only happens on debugging and works well when deploying it successfully.

